# how to bake Sun Position into Sun object animation

Tags: python, animation, keyframes

I am using the "Lighting: Sun Position" add-on that is controlling my Sun light object position, which works and renders correctly on my local host.  However for the Sheep-IT farm I apparently have to "[bake](https://forum.sheepit-renderfarm.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=1376)" this into the Sun light object position and am working a python script:

```
sun = bpy.data.objects["Sun"]
for iframe in range(bpy.context.scene.frame_start, bpy.context.scene.frame_end + 1, 1):
    bpy.context.scene.frame_current = iframe
    print( bpy.context.scene.sun_pos_properties.time )
    sun.keyframe_insert( data_path="location", frame=iframe )
```

However the sun_pos_properties.time is always printing the time (for frame #1), even though it is animated, and the inserted keys are also not changing.  Can some kind brilliant person give me a hint on how to complete this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler than I thought:

```
sun = bpy.data.objects["Sun"]
sun.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.nla.bake( frame_start=1, frame_end=10, bake_types={'OBJECT'} )
```